# Is a finite covering of a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold still $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, hodge-theory

A compact complex manifold is called a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold if for every pair $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$, every smooth $d$-closed $(p,q)$-form $\eta$ on $X$, $\eta$ is $d$-exact iff $\partial$-exact iff $\bar{\partial}$-exact iff $\partial\bar{\partial}$-exact.

Classical Hodge theory shows all compact Kähler manifolds are $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifolds, but not vice versa.

According to Theorem 5.22 of *Real homotopy theory of Kähler manifolds* (by Deligne et el.), given a bimeromorphic morphism $X\to Y$ of compact complex manifolds, if $X$ is a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold, then we know $Y$ is also a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold.

I wonder what happens in the other direction. Explicitly, if $M\to N$ is a finite covering of compact complex manifolds, and $N$ is a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold, do we have that $M$ is a  $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold?

Answer (score 2):

This question is natural and valuable.

EDIT: I don't know the case of finite covering.
But if we still consider a bimeromorphic morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$. As far as I know, the converse of [DGMS] has been confirmed in the case $\text{dim}\leq 3$ (which is maybe the best possible result up to now) by
*S. Rao--S. Yang--X. Yang, Dolbeault cohomologies of blowing up complex manifolds.
J. Math. Pures Appl. (9) 130 (2019), 68–92.*

To prove this claim,  they established Dolbeault and De Rham blow up formulae, a characteristic of the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma also provides the energy. For more details, one can refer to Remark 4.6 in their article.